# Convolution Fitting

Tags: fitting, convolution

Here I have a piecewise function `g`:

```
f[x_] = Sqrt[0.5/(-x + 0.255)]*Exp[-Sqrt[-0.5*x + 2]] (*I use it in the piecewise function g below*);
g[y_] = Piecewise[{{f[y], 0.0 < y < 0.255}, {f[0], y <= 0.0}, {0.17, y >= 0.255}}]
```

Then I want to build a convolution function `cf` which has four arguments t, a, b and c:

```
cf[t_,a_,b_,c_] = Convolve[g[y], Exp[-1*a*(t - y)^2 + b], y, t] + c
```

So I use this convolution function to fit my data ([you can download it at Google Drive](https://goo.gl/3U7PwG)) by using `FindFit`function:

```
FindFit[data, cf[t,a,b,c], {a,b,c}, t]
```

Unfortunately, it took so much time to get a result that I suspect there is something wrong in my code.

Any comment would be much appreciated.

Comment: The way it is defined the cf function seems to depend only on a,b,c and x. Is this correct ?

Comment: In the definition `g[y]` I see  a parameter x on the rigthhand side? Is this ok?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes you are right. Sorry.

Comment: @Lotus Do you mean there is an argument `y` in the `cf` function?